# ARIMA exogenous variable out of sample

Tags: python, statsmodels

```
fit = statsmodels.api.tsa.ARIMA(efRates[0], (1,1,1), exog=ueRate).fit(transparams=False)

predicts = fit.predict(start=len(efRates[0]), end = len(efRates[0])+11, exog=ueRate, typ = 'levels')
```

Generates a

```
  File "C:\Users\Saul Ramirez\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\arima_model.py", line 720, in predict
    if self.k_exog == 1 and exog.ndim == 1:

AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'ndim'
```

Some info: `efRates[0]` and `ueRate` are lists of the same length.

`efRates[0] 
[0.030052056971642007,
 0.03917330288542586,
 0.02828475062426216,
 0.03644101079605235,
 0.03378605359919436,
 0.02743587918046455,
 0.03342745492501596,
 0.026205917483282503,
 0.030503758568976337,
 0.024550760529053202,
 0.03261189266424876,
 0.03506521240864593,
 0.027338276601998696,
 0.053725765854704746,
 0.02676967429100413,
 0.03442977438269886,
 0.033314687425925964,
 0.027406120117972988,
 0.037085495711527916,
 0.021131004053371122,
 0.03342530957311805,
 0.02011467948214261,
 0.03674645825546184,
 0.030766279328527657,
 0.022010347634637235,
 0.048441932020847935,
 0.055182794314502556,
 0.037653187998947804,
 0.054329400023020905,
 0.030487014172364307,
 0.04828703019272537,
 0.029364609341652963,
 0.04420916320116292,
 0.0245732204143899,
 0.04007219462688283,
 0.030088483595491378,
 0.04503547974992547,
 0.050414257448672777,
 0.03650945820093438,
 0.0271939590858418,
 0.043825558271225154,
 0.02887263694287208,
 0.034395655516300985,
 0.033476222069816444,
 0.02364138126589003,
 0.034956784469719566,
 0.025488157761323762,
 0.03284135171594629,
 0.0352266773873871,
 0.02578522887525815,
 0.030801158226067212,
 0.017836011389627614,
 0.03237266466197845,
 0.020781381627205192,
 0.03507981277516531,
 0.030619701683938114,
 0.0200645972051283,
 0.02340543468851082,
 0.022232375406303732,
 0.031450255120488005,
 0.030807264010862326,
 0.02520300632649576,
 0.02683432106844716,
 0.01719544921035768,
 0.022245308176032028,
 0.015787396423808154,
 0.02236691164709978,
 0.022948859956318242,
 0.018302596298743336,
 0.02356268219722402,
 0.020514907102090335,
 0.029322000183361653,
 0.030253386469667742,
 0.02389996663574461,
 0.026350732450672106,
 0.018634569853141162,
 0.02993859530565429,
 0.01762489169698181,
 0.028369112029450066,
 0.024207088908217232,
 0.019513438046869554,
 0.02149236584384482,
 0.020792834468107983,
 0.0252767276304043,
 0.025754940371044845,
 0.01633653635317383,
 0.02562719118582408,
 0.01718720874173012,
 0.02915438356543398,
 0.017238835380189263,
 0.028044663751279383,
 0.027504015027686957,
 0.020989801458819447,
 0.025215885766374995,
 0.02422123160263125,
 0.03253702270430853,
 0.02095284431753602,
 0.03241141468118923,
 0.018667854534336364,
 0.03997670839216877,
 0.022116655885610726,
 0.030336876645878957,
 0.03418820217137176,
 0.018663800522544426,
 0.02623414798030232,
 0.020524065760586897]`

`ueRate 
[4.9,
 5,
 5,
 5,
 4.9,
 4.7,
 4.8,
 4.7,
 4.7,
 4.6,
 4.6,
 4.7,
 4.7,
 4.5,
 4.4,
 4.5,
 4.4,
 4.6,
 4.5,
 4.4,
 4.5,
 4.4,
 4.6,
 4.7,
 4.6,
 4.7,
 4.7,
 4.7,
 5,
 5,
 4.9,
 5.1,
 5,
 5.4,
 5.6,
 5.8,
 6.1,
 6.1,
 6.5,
 6.8,
 7.3,
 7.8,
 8.3,
 8.7,
 9,
 9.4,
 9.5,
 9.5,
 9.6,
 9.8,
 10,
 9.9,
 9.9,
 9.7,
 9.8,
 9.9,
 9.9,
 9.6,
 9.4,
 9.5,
 9.5,
 9.5,
 9.5,
 9.8,
 9.4,
 9.1,
 9,
 9,
 9.1,
 9,
 9.1,
 9,
 9,
 9,
 8.8,
 8.6,
 8.5,
 8.2,
 8.3,
 8.2,
 8.2,
 8.2,
 8.2,
 8.2,
 8.1,
 7.8,
 7.8,
 7.8,
 7.9,
 7.9,
 7.7,
 7.5,
 7.5,
 7.5,
 7.5,
 7.3,
 7.2,
 7.2,
 7.2,
 7,
 6.7,
 6.6,
 6.7,
 6.7,
 6.3,
 6.3]`

Comment: Note: `if out_of_sample != 0 and self.k_exog > 0:
            if self.k_exog == 1 and exog.ndim == 1:
                exog = exog[:, None]
                # we need the last k_ar exog for the lag-polynomial` line 720 from arima_model.py

Comment: also, `numpy.ndim(ueRate)` returns `1`

Comment: Can you add a minimum example we can use to reproduce this error?

Comment: I added the list variables

Comment: This is a bug best reported on the issue tracker. I filed a report [here](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/2127). Will get out a fix asap. Note also that your exogenous variables for prediction should 1) be out of sample not in sample and 2) should be the same length as the number of forecasts you're making.

Comment: Thanks.  Okay, can you confirm this from a theory perspective?: so it's logically correct for the actual regression model to include the full exogenous variable `ueRate`(which is unemployment rate btw) in `fit = statsmodels.api.tsa.ARIMA(efRates[0], (1,1,1), exog=ueRate).fit(transparams=False)` but the out of sample predictions 1 year out should use what one would expect the ueRate to be only 1 year out?... in other words keep `fit` the same, but change the `ueRate` used in `predicts` to only 12 values of what I want the `ueRate` to be?

Comment: I've made the changes to arima_model.py in lines 721 and 1134 as you've listed on github but still getting attribute error

Comment: @jseabold please se above when you can

Comment: Make sure you're using the patched version.